# How to inove methods with annotation parameter prioritet

Tags: java, reflection

How to invoke methods with annotation parameter prioritet?

Got testmethods, which i should invoke with java reflection:

```
public class Testmethods {

//There are eight method, should be invocen with value prioritet.
//First method(1), last method(8)

//first method
@Test(8)
public void method1(){
    System.out.println("test");
}
.
.
.
.
//last method
@Test(1)
public void method8(){
    System.out.println("test7");
}
```

Annottation class with int parametr prioritet:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Test {
    int value();
}
```

Try to invoke it with loop:

```
   private static void start(Class c) throws Exception {
        c = Testmethods.class;
        Method[] methods = c.getDeclaredMethods();

        int before = 0;
        int after = 0;
        int annoValue = 0;

        for (Method m : methods) {
            if (m.isAnnotationPresent(BeforeSuite.class)) {
                before++;
            }
            if (m.isAnnotationPresent(AfterSuite.class)) {
                after++;
            }

            if (m.isAnnotationPresent(BeforeSuite.class) && 
                before > COUNT || m.isAnnotationPresent(AfterSuite.class) && 
                after > COUNT) {
                throw new RuntimeException("more then one");
            }

            if (m.isAnnotationPresent(BeforeSuite.class) && 
                m.getAnnotation(BeforeSuite.class).value() == 10) {
                m.invoke(c.newInstance());
            }
         }


//loop to invoke.  
//Loop invoce it in random order.       
            for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
            if (methods[i].isAnnotationPresent(Test.class) && 
               (methods[i].getAnnotation(Test.class).value() < i)) {
                methods[i].invoke(c.newInstance());
            }
        }
    }
```

But it's not work propertly.

How to inove methods with annotation parameter prioritet?

Comment: Can you add more info on "But it's not work propertly"? How is it failing? Also, the variable `c` is not declared in the code you posted, so there's no way to know for certain what it is, even if it's likely to be a class instance...

Comment: I don't see you sorting the methods by the annotation's value anywhere...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Beyond that, what is the problem you *actually* intend to solve here?

Comment: I need to invoce 8 test methods with reflection, using value prioritet. First should be method(1) last method(8), method(1) got 8 int value // method(8) got 1 int value, it's should be awoken with order: method(1), method(2) ... method(8)

Comment: Are you trying to say "invoke"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
    if (methods[i].isAnnotationPresent(Test.class) && 
           (methods[i].getAnnotation(Test.class).value() < i)) {
        methods[i].invoke(c.newInstance());
    }
}
```

To:

```
for (int priority = 8; priority> 0; priority--){
    for(Method method : methods){
        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Test.class) && 
            method.getAnnotation(Test.class).value() == i){
            method.invoke(c.newInstance());
            break; // continue outer loop
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You intend to run in reverse order of the `priority` value, so your loop should run with `i` from 8 to 1.

```
for (int i = 8; i > 0; i--) {
    if (methods[i].isAnnotationPresent(Test.class) && 
              (methods[i].getAnnotation(Test.class).value() == i)) {
        methods[i].invoke(c.newInstance());
    }
}
```

Also note that the condition should check for equality, `methods[i].getAnnotation(Test.class).value() == i`

Comment: allready try it, here is a result:                     
                                                                                                                                 
test5
                                                                                                                         Process finished with exit code 0